# Alert box for `alert($('input:number[name=userNum]').val());` does not pop-up

Tags: jquery, html

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/jquery.min.js')
script.
  function aFunction() {
  alert($('input:text[name=userName]').val());  /* alert box, works fine. */
  alert($('input:number[name=userNum]').val()); /* Some Error Here. Alert Box does not pop-up */
  }

body
 form(name='aForm', method='post', onsubmit='aFunction();')
   input(type='text', name='userName', placeholder='Enter your name')
   input(type='number', name='userNum', placeholder='Enter a number')
   button(type='submit') submit
```

The alert box pops up the Name entered, but the alert box does not pop up for the Number entered. What is the error there?

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Ok for `:text` but never heard about `:number`

Comment: If you checked your console, you'd likely see this: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input type as `number`, we can use the code like:

```
alert($('input[name=userNum]').val());
```

Since, in jquery we don't have a selector for `number` yet!
Even though we have a selector for [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert($("input[type='number'][name='userNum']").val());
```

Hope this helps,Thank you